# JQuery DataTable set default empty search Echo parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using JQuery DataTable with server side processing. And I've written this code:

```
public List<VacationRequest> GetVacationRequestsWithProfiles(int displayStart, int displayLength, out int allDataCount, out int filteredDatacount, string searchParam = "", string searchDir = "")
{
....

    switch(searchDir)
                {
                    case "asc":
                        requests = requests.OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).ThenByDescending(x=>x.DateEnd).Skip(displayStart).Take(displayLength);
                        break;
                    case "desc":
                    requests = requests.OrderByDescending(x => x.FirstName).ThenByDescending(x=>x.DateEnd).Skip(displayStart).Take(displayLength);
                        break;
                    default:
                        requests = requests.OrderBy(x=>x.VacationRequestState).ThenByDescending(x=>x.DateEnd).Skip(displayStart).Take(displayLength);
                        break;
                }

....
}
```

The problem: I need to get `default` (empty) search parameter to this method, when page loaded. How I may resolve this?
This is a part of `JS` code:

```
  "aoColumns": [
    { "data": "ID", "visible": false, bSortable: false, bSearchable: false },
    { "data": "Name" },
    {
        "data": "VacationRequestStatus",
        bSortable: false,
        bSearchable: false,
        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {              
            return '<div class = "' + data + '"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign requested-img"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok accept-img"> </span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove decline-img"></span> </div>';
        }
    },
    { "mData": "Position", bSortable: false, bSearchable: false },
    { "mData": "DateStart", bSortable: false, bSearchable: false },
    { "mData": "DateEnd", bSortable: false, bSearchable: false },
    {
        bSortable: false,
        bSearchable: false,
        data: null,
        className: "center",
        defaultContent: '<button class="btn btn-danger decline-button">Decline</button> <button class="btn btn-primary accept-button">Accept</button>'
    }
    ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, what does it come through as on your action method if not "" (empty string)?

Comment: Also check out DTSharp a v useful plugin for dealing with DataTable params https://github.com/publiux/DTSharp

Comment: I did it. It was necessary to check '0' column for my task.

Answer (score 0):

because dont know where u put ajax try add this command ine the line before aoColumns

```
"destroy" : true,
"aoColumns": [
```

thats command to stop data display in datable but after search data will diplay hope solve ur problems